# Media, Maria: А или Я?

Tags: транскрипция

Окончания слов "-ia" мы обычно произносим как "-ия": Мария, мелодия, пародия и т.д. Но при этом говорим "масс-медиа". А недавно я встретила в книге прочтение "Мариа".
Есть ли какие-то нормы прочтения этого окончания в русском языке?

Comment: Очевидно - зависит от языка оригинала.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну какие тут могут быть **нормы**?! 
Только аналогии... А они позволяют произносить и так и так. 
Сравните с грузинскими фамилиями на "-иа/-ия". 
Хотя по большому счету русский язык до сих пор избегает т.н. зияния гласных, так что "-ия" звучит более "по-русски","-иа" - подчеркнуто "иностранно".

Имя - Мария, без вариантов, как бы оно ни писалось в языке-источнике.

Comment: А как быть в случае с [Антонио Мариа Коста][1]?

[1]:http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0,_%D0%90%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BE_%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0

Comment: Я думаю - как и со всеми Мари**я**ми. Не вижу причин ломать язык, подчеркивая, что он именно Мариа.

Уточняю. Как писать - это можно обсуждать, но говорить - Мария. По другому и не выговоришь...

Comment: Я тоже так думаю! Меня это "Мариа" жутко коробит.

Comment: Эрих МариЯ Ремарк :-))